# Query unique pair of nodes when pair orders is not important in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to compare users with according to their common interests in this [graph](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=egyeyb).
I know why the following query produces duplicate pairs but can't think of a good way in cypher to avoid it. Is there any way to do it without looping in cypher?

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ start n=node(*) match p=n-[:LIKES]->item<-[:LIKES]-other where n <> other return n.name,other.name,collect(item.name) as common, count(*) as freq order by freq desc;
==> +-----------------------------------------------+
==> | n.name | other.name | common           | freq |
==> +-----------------------------------------------+
==> | "u1"   | "u2"       | ["f1","f2","f3"] | 3    |
==> | "u2"   | "u1"       | ["f1","f2","f3"] | 3    |
==> | "u1"   | "u3"       | ["f1","f2"]      | 2    |
==> | "u3"   | "u2"       | ["f1","f2"]      | 2    |
==> | "u2"   | "u3"       | ["f1","f2"]      | 2    |
==> | "u3"   | "u1"       | ["f1","f2"]      | 2    |
==> | "u4"   | "u3"       | ["f1"]           | 1    |
==> | "u4"   | "u2"       | ["f1"]           | 1    |
==> | "u4"   | "u1"       | ["f1"]           | 1    |
==> | "u2"   | "u4"       | ["f1"]           | 1    |
==> | "u1"   | "u4"       | ["f1"]           | 1    |
==> | "u3"   | "u4"       | ["f1"]           | 1    |
==> +-----------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to avoid having duplicates in the form of `a--b` and `b--a`, you can exclude one of the combinations in your WHERE clause with

```
WHERE ID(a) < ID(b)
```

making your above query

```
start n=node(*) match p=n-[:LIKES]->item<-[:LIKES]-other where ID(n) < ID(other) return n.name,other.name,collect(item.name) as common, count(*) as freq order by freq desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see that you use (*) as a start point, which mean to loop through the whole graph and make each node as a start point.. So the output is different, not duplicate as you say..

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| n.name | other.name | common           | freq |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| "u2"   | "u1"       | ["f1","f2","f3"] | 3    |
```

not equal to:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| n.name | other.name | common           | freq |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| "u1"   | "u2"       | ["f1","f2","f3"] | 3    |
```

So, I see that if you try using an index and set a start point, there won't be any duplicates.

```
start n=node:someIndex(name='C') match p=n-[:LIKES]->item<-[:LIKES]-other where n <> other return n.name,other.name,collect(item.name) as common, count(*) as freq order by freq desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that is why i said without looping because I did not want to call each node in a loop. That is a more general problem with neo4j. For undirected graphs, the common objects between (u1,u2) is the same as (u2,u1) so is there any way to avoid double calculation

Comment: You are right it's a problem as you explained, but i think that using an index won't make such a problem, as I said in the answer `n=node:someIndex(name='u1') `